# Invitation Listener not working smack 4.1

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

I'm using smack 4.1 in my application,
i'm able to send invitations but I'm failing receiving them

In fact when debugging i was receiving the invitation in my `ChatMessageListener()`
,in the packet Extension i can get the whole invitation but i don't want to pares XML .

my `InvitationLisenter()` is *never* called

```
final MultiUserChatManager manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
    manager.addInvitationListener(new InvitationListener() {
        @Override
        public void invitationReceived(XMPPConnection xmppConnection, MultiUserChat multiUserChat, String s, String s1, String s2, Message message) {
            try {
                multiUserChat.join(mUserName);
            } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of room invites in xmpp ,

Direct Invitation

that is send as a normal message and received with `ChatMessageListener()`
,and i'm using this code to get the invite from the message

```
GroupChatInvitation invite = (GroupChatInvitation)result.getExtension("x","jabber:x:conference");
```

and
Mediated Invitation

that is received with `InvitationLisenter()`